# Storing password the right way using java

Tags: java, .net, passwords, byte, sha1

i got an old system using .Net and users passwords already stored using SHA1 with salt , iam looking to have new version using Java to check password on login,

original .net code was done using this **http://www.aspheute.com/english/20040105.asp**

i need to have the same using java , but the problem is that java uses signed byte while .net uses unsigned ,

so the final hashed value for both not the same .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you given a look at [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) and [MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html?is-external=true)?

```
MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
digest.update(password.getBytes());
digest.update(salt.getBytes());
String hash = DigestUtils.sha1Hex(digest.digest());
// or
byte[] hash = DigestUtils.sha1(digest.digest());
```

Comment: thanks @dcm for prompt help, the problem when convert the salt integer to byte, so in .net its unsigned byte to works different than java : i.e. assume 
<html>
<code>
int pSal = 328545744; 

saltBytes[0] = (byte) (pSalt >> 24); 

saltBytes[1] = (byte) (pSalt >> 16); // --> in java this value is -107 while in c# it is 147_ 

saltBytes[2] = (byte) (pSalt >> 8); 

saltBytes[3] = (byte) (pSalt); </code> </html>

Comment: The only thing you could do is
`int unsignedSalt = salt & 0xFF;` to get the unsigned value of the salt then.

Comment: Can you elaborate please.

Comment: All primitives in java are signed, so the only way to get the unsigned value is to upcast it by either using the method above or by using the Byte.toUnsignedInt method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt-byte- Also Byte.compareUnsigned was introduced in java 9 so that might help you.

Comment: thanks alot for the help, now having the unsigned fixed , the problem is back to how to get the sha1 byte[] from passwords[] and salt int[] , while the MessageDigest takes only byte[] , and if we convert the salt int[] to byte[] then we are back to square zero ?

Comment: Try the [Byte.compareUnsigned(x, y)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#compareUnsigned-byte-byte-), it will treat them both as unsigned, that way you won't have to upcast your salt.